# memsql - Formatted Query takes more time than Unformatted query

Tags: performance, formatting, singlestore

Why Does Formatted Query takes more time than Unformatted query ?
Also Note I have ran the queries many times (So plan caching is taken in account)

Does it mean memsql is poor in query format handling ?

For instance I tried the following query(unformatted)

```
select count(*) from users where users.rep > 5;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      589 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

But amazingly the same query when is formatted takes more time

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  users
WHERE
  users.rep > 5 ;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      589 |
+----------+
1 row in set (1.39 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With memsql, you have to wait for code compilation the first time you run a query, and the formatted query is considered "a different query" than the unformatted one.  Whitespace matters!  Try running the formatted version again.

In general, MemSQL queries are fast only the second time you run them.
See http://docs.memsql.com/4.0/concepts/codegen/

Comment: I ran both the formatted and the unformatted queries multiple times . still the same result. Why does memsql handles the formatted queries so badly ?

Comment: There should be absolutely no difference at execution time...  You can use information_schema.plancache to double check if you are recompiling many slightly different queries.   But there should be no difference whatsoever in the performance of those queries.

Comment: Try it and let me know @Joseph. I got better results with unformatted queries.

Comment: Hey ysaditya, can you go to chat.memsql.com?  This should be a straightforward issue to debug.